# GitPython with remotes

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to solve an easy task with git in python. Actually I just want something like this

```
git clome remote-repo
git pull
edit file
git commit file
git push
rm -rf remote-repo
```

So just change a file and commit it and push it right away. But I have my problems get my head arround the documentation http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html
This is what I got so far

```
import git
import shutil
import os

repo_url = 'git@git.internal.server:users/me/mytest'
repo_dir = '/tmp/test/repo'
work_file_name = 'testFile'
work_file = os.path.join(repo_dir, work_file_name)
if os.path.isdir(repo_dir):
   shutil.rmtree(repo_dir)
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url, repo_dir)

git = repo.git
git.pull()
new_file_path = os.path.join(repo.working_tree_dir, work_file_name)
f = open(new_file_path, 'w')
f.write("just some test")
f.close()
repo.index.commit("test commit")

git.push()
shutil.rmtree(repo_dir)
```

It actually creates a commit and pushes it to the server, but it contains no changes, so the file I tried to write is empty. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stage the file/change before the commit:

```
repo.index.add([new_file_path])
```

As a side note: The following line overrides your import and might lead to errors if you ever expand your script:

```
git = repo.git
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried it with index.add before, but forgot the brackets and got an error.